# How to convert Current date as a Date datatype in typescript or javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datetime

I am using the Below function to generate the Date and Time in my angular app but it's returning as a string instead of date&time dataType.

```js
getCurrentDateAndTime() {
  const today = new Date();
  const datePipe = new DatePipe('en-IN');
  return datePipe.transform(today, 'dd/MM/yyyy, hh:mm a');
}
```

can suggest doing better way for generating Date datatype in the format 'dd/mm/yyyy , hh:mm am'

Comment: Do you want string? or Date object?

Comment: @adiga Date object in this format 'dd/mm/yyyy , hh:mm am'

Comment: all generate in string only

Comment: @praga2050 means can't generate a Date obj in a specific format

Comment: posted my another version see if it help

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using the datePipe.transform method? It's job is to create a string for representation so if you want a Date returned, you don't need the datePipe, you can just return `new Date()` (ofc you don't need a method for that)

Regarding your edit, you don't keep date objects in a specific format, it just keeps the information about the point in time, you usually only apply a format once you want to display it and that's when the datePipe.transform method comes into play.

Comment: i need date in 'dd/mm/yyyy , hh:mm am' format as Date datatype

Comment: @ShubhamSingh—that's a non–sequitur.  'dd/mm/yyyy , hh:mm am' is a string format, a Date is an object that has a single data value: an offset in milliseconds since the ECMAScript epoch. It also has some methods for various functions. That's it. It does not store format, timezone or colour of the sky.

Answer (score 0):

Date type value is numeric internally. The string representation can vary according to your choice. In your case:

```
const d = new Date();
const dAsString = d.toLocaleString('en-IN');
```

Result: **"23/12/2020, 8:46:27 am"**

Comment: I need output as a Date object but in your code snippet it's giving type as a string I need type as a Date object

Comment: @ShubhamSingh I'm saying that the Date object you need is `const today = new Date()`. Any string representation will never be the Date object. It's not clear to me what you really need. Maybe if you can post the full code.

Answer (score 0):

May be another way using `getTime()`You have to use ISO only. See this Stackoverflow Link

[What is the "right" JSON date format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/what-is-the-right-json-date-format)

```
import { DatePipe } from "@angular/common";
import { Component, VERSION } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"],
  providers: [DatePipe]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular " + VERSION.major;

  dataFormatted: string = "";
  dateInMilliSecond: number;
  dataISO: string = '';

  constructor(protected datePipe: DatePipe) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const today = new Date();
    const datePipe = new DatePipe("en-IN");
    this.dataFormatted = datePipe.transform(today, "dd/MM/yyyy, hh:mm a");
    this.dateInMilliSecond = new Date().getTime();
    this.dataISO = new Date().toISOString();
  }
}


{{dataFormatted}}
<br/>
<br/>
In MilliSecond: {{dateInMilliSecond | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy, hh:mm a'}}
<br/>
<br/>

ISO Date : {{dataISO}}
```

Comment: I need to send the date obj value to the server so pipe inside interpolation doesn't work for  me

Comment: You have to use ISO dateFormat only https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10286204/what-is-the-right-json-date-format